Installing cantools in msys2 in venv
I'm trying to get cantools package working in a venv inside MSYS2 installation (on Windows). But it requires python-can, which requires pywin32. I did install mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pywin32 and the global pip list does show pywin32 package version 308. But if I start a venv and attempt to install python-can I get this error:
13:48:37   ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 2) because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
13:48:37   
13:48:37   The conflict is caused by:
13:48:37       python-can 4.4.2 depends on pywin32>=305; platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
13:48:37       python-can 4.4.0 depends on pywin32>=305; platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
13:48:37       python-can 4.3.1 depends on pywin32>=305; platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
13:48:37       python-can 4.3.0 depends on pywin32>=305; platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
13:48:37       python-can 4.2.2 depends on pywin32>=305; platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
13:48:37       python-can 4.2.1 depends on pywin32>=305; platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
13:48:37       python-can 4.2.0 depends on pywin32>=305; platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
13:48:37       python-can 4.1.0 depends on pywin32; platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
13:48:37       python-can 4.0.0 depends on windows-curses; platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
13:48:37       python-can 3.3.4 depends on windows-curses; platform_system == "Windows"

Adding pywin32 to the requirements.txt file generates this error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)

Some other answer suggested using the pypiwin32 package. But it seems to only work with python 2.7. I've tried adding it to the requirements.txt file, but it generates error outlined here.
Is there any way to resolve this?
Python 3.12
